# How to locate this specific element?

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-chromedriver, element, selenium-ide

So I was using selenium ide for some automation works and had real fun with it. But lately, when I'm in https://pay.google.com/gp/w/home/paymentmethods and try to click this button which says "Add payment method", selenium cant find it at all.

things I tried:

Css.finder:

```
css=.b3id-payment-method-add-instrument-link span
```

Xpath:idRelative

```
xpath=//body[@id='iframeBody']/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[4]/a/div/div/span
```

Xpath:position

```
xpath=//div[4]/a/div/div/span
```

xpath:innerText

```
xpath=//span[contains(.,'Add payment method')]
```

Even if I record clicks, selenium ide records things like

```
select frame index=0
click css=.b3id-payment-method-add-instrument-link span
```

which also doesn't work

What should I do to locate this specific button?

Answer (score 0):

```
<iframe frameborder="0" src="about:blank" id="mainWidget_:0Iframe" name="mainWidget_:0Iframe" style="border: 0px; vertical-align: initial; display: block; width: 100%; min-height: calc((100vh - 69px) - 113px); position: static; top: auto; visibility: visible; z-index: auto; background-color: inherit; height: 510px; left: auto; opacity: 1; transition: all 0s ease 0s;" title=""></iframe>
```

Your element is in an iframe switch to it.

```
<div class="b3id-info-message-html b3-info-message-html" data-was-visible="true"><span data-was-visible="true">Add payment method</span></div>
```

a simple css selector would be

```
.b3id-info-message-html.b3-info-message-html
```